# Mapping an object to CoreData with 2 classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

So this is the first time i'm trying to map objects into CoreData, I think I got it right, but I have few issues. First of all, I just don't know if I'm mapping it the right way and the second one is that I get a success response but without objects mapped.

I have 2 objects DbRestError & DbRestCategory. DbRestError contain the error from the server and DbRestCategory contain the category itself. the are both coming back from the same response but RestKit seems unable to map them.

Those are the objects:

**DbRestError**

```
@interface DbRestError : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * statusCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * errorTitle;

@end
```

**DbRestCategory**

```
@interface DbRestCategory : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * idNum;

@end
```

**This is how I initialize my CoreData with RestKit:**

```
- (void)setup
{
    self.objectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"Setting up store at %@", path);
    [self.objectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path
                              fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil
                                   withConfiguration:nil
                                             options:@{ NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES, NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES }
                                               error:nil];

    [self.objectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
}
```

**This is how I initialize my RestKit client:**

```
- (void)initRestClient
{
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kWebServiceBaseURL];
    self.manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [self.manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [self.manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [self.manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].responseDescriptors];
    [self.manager addRequestDescriptorsFromArray:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestDescriptors];
    [self.manager.HTTPClient.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:MAX_CONCURRENT_OPERATION_COUNT];
    [self.manager setManagedObjectStore:[[MainDb sharedDb] objectStore]];

    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:self.manager];

    self.requestMethod = RKRequestMethodGET;
    self.statusCode = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

    RKRoute *categoriesRoute = [RKRoute routeWithClass:[DbRestCategory class] pathPattern:kGetCategories method:self.requestMethod];
    categoriesRoute.shouldEscapePath = YES;
    [self.manager.router.routeSet addRoute:categoriesRoute];

    //  @@yosi -- Error Mapping
    //
    //
    RKEntityMapping *errorMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DbRestError" inManagedObjectStore:[[MainDb sharedDb] objectStore]];
    [errorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"statusCode" : @"statusCode", @"description" : @"errorTitle" }];

    //  @@yosi -- Categories Mapping
    //
    //
    RKEntityMapping *categoryMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DbRestCategory" inManagedObjectStore:[[MainDb sharedDb] objectStore]];
    [categoryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"id" : @"idNum", @"name" : @"title" }];

    RKObjectMapping *categoriesMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RestCategories class]];
    [categoriesMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"categories" mapping:categoryMapping];
    [categoriesMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"error" toKeyPath:@"error" withMapping:errorMapping]];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:categoriesMapping
                                                                                                        method:self.requestMethod
                                                                                                   pathPattern:kGetCategories
                                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                                   statusCodes:self.statusCode]];
}
```

**This is how I'm doing the request itself:**

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:[[DbRestCategory alloc] init] path:nil parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

**This is how the JSON looks like:**

```
{
error: {
statusCode: 10,
description: "success"
},
categories: [
    {
        id: "3",
    name: "cate 3"
    },
    {
        id: "4",
    name: "cate 4"
    },
    {
        id: "5",
    name: "cate 5"
    },
    {
        id: "1",
    name: "cate 1"
    },
    {
        id: "6",
    name: "cate 6"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
    name: "cate 2"
    }
             ]
}
```

Can someone please help me to understand why i'm getting a response without any objects?

Comment: `error` and `categories` are under same response. Why are you using method `getObject` instead of `getObjectsAtPath`? You can add two response descriptor map the two entities.

Comment: @AnushaK Yeah I did that, but still it's not working. Now I'm getting this error: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restkit/2u5Ke_FnaZU

Answer (score 0):

Try the request mapping like this,

```
// Request Mapping

// Map error
RKEntityMapping *errorMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DbRestError" inManagedObjectStore:[[MainDb sharedDb] objectStore]];
[errorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"statusCode" : @"statusCode", @"description" : @"errorTitle" }];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping method:self.requestMethod pathPattern:kGetCategories keyPath:@"error" statusCodes:self.statusCode]];

// Map Category
RKEntityMapping *categoryMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DbRestCategory" inManagedObjectStore:[[MainDb sharedDb] objectStore]];
[categoryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"id" : @"idNum", @"name" : @"title" }];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:categoriesMapping method:self.requestMethod pathPattern:kGetCategories keyPath:@"categories" statusCodes:self.statusCode]];
```